# Automatize adding/renaming folders in an Express.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a simple Node.js Express website, and I'm running the following commands:

```
cd node
npm install pug express
express project_name
cd project_name && npm install
npm start
```

When this runs, it's creating the `/public` folder, along with `/images`, `/javascripts`, `stylesheets`.

Is there a way I can automatically replace these with `/img`, `/js`, `css` when I create it?

I'm simply trying to have a quick set of commands that allow me to create a simplistic Express server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1) Bash Script**

One way would be to add [mv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv) to your list of commands

```
mv images img      # rename images to img
mv javascripts js  # rename javascripts to js
mv stylesheets css # rename stylesheets to css
```

which you can then automatize into a simple bash script

**my-express.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ "$#" == "1" ]; then
  express $1
  cd $1 && npm install
  mv public/images public/img
  mv public/javascripts public/js
  mv public/stylesheets public/css
  npm start
else
  echo "usage my-express <project-name>"
fi
```

and use it like

```
./my-express.sh project_name
```

You might also want to make this script [global](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162134/how-to-execute-a-bash-script-without-typing) and give it [execution permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-ran-from-termina) to provide a generic cli tool used like

```
my-express project_name
```

**Option 2) Node script**

Same idea as the bash script except written using node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var projectName = process.argv[2];

var commands = [
  'npm install',
  'mv public/images public/img',
  'mv public/javascripts public/js',
  'mv public/stylesheets public/css',
  'npm start'
];

if (typeof projectName !== 'string' || projectName.length < 1) {
  console.log('Usage: node my-express <project-name>');
} else {
  var cmd = ['express ' + projectName,'cd ' + projectName]
    .concat(commands)
    .join(' && ');

  console.log('Executing\n', cmd.replace(/\&\&/g, '&&\n'));

  exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log(stdout);
    }
  });
}
```

You also need to create a `package.json` in the same directory with the following contents

```
{
  "name": "my-express",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "bin": {
    "my-express": "./my-express.js"
  }
}
```

And then run `npm install -g` which links the script to a location on the path, so you can use it like any other shell command

Usage

```
my-express my_project
```

**Option 3) Custom express-generator build**

Fork the [express-generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator) project and change [these 3 lines](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/master/bin/express#L149-L151) to what you need them to be